# Getting 403 while accessing secured endpoints in SpringBoot even when the roles are matching and user credentials are correct

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

Below is the Security configuration class:-

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityManager extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails user=User.builder().username("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("secret")).
                roles("USER").build();
        UserDetails userAdmin=User.builder().username("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("secret")).
                roles("ADMIN").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,userAdmin);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/hello*").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Below is the controller I'm accessing:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/helloworld",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sampleGetter()
    {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/helloinnerclass",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public InnerClass sampleInnerGetter()
    {
        return new InnerClass("Title","Value");
    }
    class InnerClass
    {
        String title;
        String value;

        public InnerClass(String title, String value) {
            this.title = title;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

While triggering above mentioned endpoints via Postman, I'm getting 403 status code. Below is the error screenshot:- [image]

I've not mentioned anything related to security in the properties file in the project so am sure basic security is not being handled through properties file.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code on Stackoverflow, just post the correctly formatted error message itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable `httpBasic` in your security filter?

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/hello*").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

I've created an entire [sample project](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/5a7ebc57fbc28359586471307c5a4b0111f01faf/samples/in-memory-auth/) that uses both basic and formLogin

The security configuration is similar to yours, but I prefer not the show the passwords in clear text in the actual application

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$C8c78G3SRJpy268vInPUFu.3lcNHG9SaNAPdSaIOy.1TJIio0cmTK")
            .roles("USER")
            .build(),
        builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$XvWhl0acx2D2hvpOPd/rPuPA48nQGxOFom1NqhxNN9ST1p9lla3bG")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build()
    );
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        //application security
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/non-secure/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
    ;
    // @formatter:on
}
```

and we can demonstrate through a [simple test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/5a7ebc57fbc28359586471307c5a4b0111f01faf/samples/in-memory-auth/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/InMemoryAuthTests.java#L103) case that it works

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("user / 123 basic authentication")
void userBasic() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(
        get("/secure")
            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String("user:123".getBytes()))
    )
        .andExpect(authenticated())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
    ;
}
```

I wrote a [simple test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/5a7ebc57fbc28359586471307c5a4b0111f01faf/samples/in-memory-auth/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/InMemoryAuthTests.java#L96-L100) that encoded my passwords

```java
@Test
void printPasswords() {
    System.out.println("123 = "+passwordEncoder.encode("123"));
    System.out.println("password = "+passwordEncoder.encode("password"));
}
```

Comment: In the userDetailsService() method, the strings that you have provided next to bcrypt, where did you get those values from?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the [test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/5a7ebc57fbc28359586471307c5a4b0111f01faf/samples/in-memory-auth/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/InMemoryAuthTests.java#L96-L100)

Comment: You could also do  `.password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))`

Comment: Couldn't understand the Base64.encodeBase64String("user:123".getBytes()).I mean where this string "user:123" is coming from?

Comment: That is the http-basic authentication [protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617), it is in the format `username:password`. Explanation [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/)

I've linked both the [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617) and a [tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/) for you